# How to get POST form data using VERTX handlers?

Tags: java, vert.x, forms, http-post

I am able to get the form data using the buffer handler, but it is a void function and I cannot return the form data values. Have about 4-7 forms total, I don't want to end up writing the same handler over and over because the default function is void.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head><title>Login Page</title></head>
<body>
    <a href="/activateUserPage">activate user</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="/login">log in</a>
    <br/>

    <form id='login' action='/login' method='post'>
        <fieldset >
            <legend>Login</legend>
            <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

            <label for='username' >UserName: </label>
            <input type='text' name='username' id='username'  maxlength="50"/>

            <label for='password' >Password: </label>
            <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50"/>

            <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
        </fieldset>
    </form>         
</body>    
</html>
```

java:

```
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.QueryStringDecoder;
import org.vertx.java.core.Handler;
import org.vertx.java.core.Vertx;
import org.vertx.java.core.buffer.Buffer;
import org.vertx.java.core.http.HttpServer;
import org.vertx.java.core.http.HttpServerRequest;
import org.vertx.java.core.http.RouteMatcher;
import org.vertx.java.deploy.Verticle;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: yao
 * Date: 1/17/13
 * Time: 2:22 PM
 */

public class Main extends Verticle
{
    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("starting the vertx stuff");
        final String host = "localhost";
        final String port = "8181";

        Vertx vertx = Vertx.newVertx();
        HttpServer httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer();

        ...

        httpServer.requestHandler(new Handler<HttpServerRequest>()
        {
            public void handle(HttpServerRequest req)
            {
                String path = req.path;

                /* start mapping of page urls*/
                // redirect user to the login page
                if (path.equals("/"))
                {
                    req.response.sendFile(dir + "html/loginPage.html");
                }
                ...

                /* end mapping of page urls*/

                /* start mapping of form urls */
                // login
                else if (path.equals(login))
                {
                    mainLogin();
                    getFormData(req);
                }
                ...

                /* end mapping of form urls */

                /* all other pages */
                else
                {
                    req.response.end("404 - page no exist");
                }
            }
        });

        System.out.println("vertx listening to: " + host + " " + port);
        httpServer.listen(Integer.valueOf(port), host);
    }

    ...

    private void getFormData(final HttpServerRequest req)
    {
        req.bodyHandler(new Handler<Buffer>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(Buffer buff)
            {
                String contentType = req.headers().get("Content-Type");
                if ("application/x-www-form-urlencoded".equals(contentType))
                {
                    QueryStringDecoder qsd = new QueryStringDecoder(buff.toString(), false);
                    Map<String, List<String>> params = qsd.getParameters();
                    System.out.println(params);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what i did in the end is basically this:

do the ajax call using post, the data from the form needs to be serialized.

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/login",
    data: $('#frm_login').serialize(),
    success: function(data)
...
```

in the backend, vertx receives this data as a buffer. rest is to parse the buffer by splitting by "&" and "=".

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
String[] paramSplits = buffer.toString().split("&");
String[] valueSplits;

if (paramSplits.length > 1)
{
    for (String param : paramSplits)
    {
        valueSplits = param.split("=");
        if (valueSplits.length > 1)
        {
            // add this check to handle empty phone number fields
            params.put(decode(valueSplits[0]), decode(valueSplits[1]));
        }
    }
}
```

hope this will help others!

Comment: Yao jiang,  I'm also trying to do something similar.  I have a couple of questions:

1) how did you hook the javascript to the html?  did you just embed it into the header or footer?

2) the code that you show in the answer, is the buffer object from the HttpServerRequest object?  Where is that from?

Comment: 1. what do you mean by hook? i separate the js and html, just set the source of js in the head then set up for functions for the elements 2. the buffer is from vertx,--> request.bodyHandler(new Handler<Buffer>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(Buffer buffer)
            { --> this is usually what i see in the examples so i just followed it. that code is in the java:

Comment: 1). that's what i meant by "hook" so thank you. I suspected as much but wanted to confirm.  2) I see.  Are you using the vertx WebServer mod by any chance?

Comment: not sure what WebServer mod is. im just following whatever the vertx examples show me.

Comment: ah, then no. im just using vanilla vertx.

Answer (score 7):

Nowadays BodyHandler is provided by vertx, using it isExpectMultipart will be set to true and you will be able to read form attributes as

```
request.getFormAttribute("username");//to read input named username.
```

just add this line before your actual handler:

```
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
```

Comment: For vert.x 3+ versions this should be accepted the answer.

Answer (score 4):

For java this worked perfectly:

```
request.expectMultiPart(true);
    request.endHandler(req->{
      String text = request.formAttributes().get("bigtext"); 
      //got it here
      //do something ...
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the formAttributes on the http request. Here is an example in scala

```
  req.expectMultiPart(true) //Will expect a form
  req.endHandler({

    req.formAttributes() //This is used to access form attributes

    //some code with attributes

  })
```

Reference: http://vertx.io/core_manual_java.html#handling-multipart-form-attributes